# css color changes on different computers

Tags: css, colors

Hi a have a website and in some computers, don't no why the red color is changed, I uploaded an image where are two screenshots of the same webpage of the same site as you can see the red color is different, I understand change on font rendering but the color?

Can anyone can explain me why this is happening and how to solved it?

The original color should be: #B73A41 and  some computers this color is turned to: #a54546

http://tny.im/230

Comment: Is the change happening to the code or just the color is changing? On the latter case, it depends on the screen monitor color mode.

Comment: I understand that if I see the website on different computers the red color maybe looks different because different monitor adjustments and technologies, but if i took a screenshot of the website on one computer and send the file to another the color should looks the same, I extract the wrong red color from GIMP, so its happening for some reason the browser is changing the color.

Comment: Probably something to do with color correction. Does [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/ICC_color_correction_in_Firefox) help? If the picture does contain a color profile, it may be possible to remove it with a program such as Photoshop.

Comment: I cant tell if is happening on code level, i dont have access right now to the computer taht is displaying the wrong color. This website was designed on PDF first and I remember that sometimes I saw the red color different, I also remember I asked the designer why your color red is different than other versions of the same PDF and he couldnt explain why, but know is happening again on css, its really weird

Comment: You can't change the way a specific hex code renders on different machines/browsers. For example, on my computer, Safari renders colours different to Chrome and Firefox. If I take a screenshot and colour-pick the colours in Photoshop, they're different. There's nothing you can do except try a different colour that might not have as much variance.

Comment: The red color is set on css, so is not an image, the only image i use is the icon you saw of the dollar man, but the white color renders the same, so tis not a problem with a color profile

Comment: Yes I was thinking to use another red, I belived that might be a problem with the way browser / OS / machine handle the colors, sad news I really liked the color, but need to be changed

Comment: I never had this kind of issue, I knew about the color variance but this vairance is heavy, I will search in deep why this color have that huge amount of variance, let you know, also I will try to define the color in rgb, maybe that helps.

Comment: Thinking its more an issue with the icc profiles used by the different monitors. Colour will never be the same on various devices, it's always a close match but hardly ever the true colour as it should be. Source? I have various pc's and monitors for dev purposes for the same reason. Might be useful to use a spectrometer on your monitor to ensure that atleast you get the right colours during development.

Answer (score 0):

Could this be a caching issue - have you set the image to different colors in the past?

Perhaps there is a transparency layer over the image, like on :hover?

Otherwise I can't think of any reason the color would appear different.  Doesn't matter what monitor they're using unless they're sending the screenshot as a photograph.

If you're still stumped, get control of their computer and see for yourself.

Comment: If it is a cache issue you can force a reload in most new browsers with ctrl + shift + r.